# iOS app to take photo and send to specified email address with unique ID

Tags: iphone, ios

I am fairly new to iOS app developemt but I am doing some research on behalf of a client who wants to create a native or hybrid iOS app that allows users to take a photo using their iPhone camera and proceed to automatically send that picture (upon confirmation by user), with a unique identifier attached to the email, to a predetermined email address.  Is this reasonably straightforward? Are there any privacy issues that need to be addressed when sending this type of data?

Also, how would that user be identified so that the relevant response can be sent back to them?  Basically, what happens is the photo of the product is received and that product is manually sourced from a chain of partner merchants.  Then, the prices and merchant details are sent back to the user.  How might this work on iOS?

Many thanks, sorry if this sounds too vague but just ask for more details.

Comment: What's the significance of the unique identifier? Why can't you use their email address to send the response back to them? In a native app you can't force the user to send only to a certain email address, you can pre-populate it the field though.

Comment: @CarlVeazey You're right.  There is no immediate reason I can think of that the ID could not be the email address.  Is it possible, in the native app, to upload the image to a server and then have the backend forward that image to our own email address?

Comment: Yes, absolutely you can upload the image data to whatever web service you like using a variety of built-in and third-party frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

You can Use PHP for backend For Uploading the image in server and Generating a unique code for each pictures uploaded by user.

So the process is like iPhone -->upload.php -->get the response link from php and mail that link to specified